# Matching function types?

Tags: scala

In short - I don't understand why this compiles:

```
var a : Any = null
type MyType = () => Unit
a match { case f : MyType => }
```

while this doesn't

```
var a : Any = null
a match { case f : () => Unit => }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `case f : () => Unit =>` part,
`case` statement breaks the type from action in first flat arrow (`=>`) it sees.

```
a match { case f : MyType => }
//                        ^
```

So in later example it breaks the statement as follows,

```
a match { case f : () => Unit => }
//                    ^
```

And tries to match with the type `()` instead of `() => Unit`, which is not a type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can it be helped somehow (without explicit  type declaration), with for example extra brackets? I tried a couple variants but nothing worked.

Comment: Try `Function0[Unit]`. Actually `() => A` is a syntactic suger for `Function0[A]`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have two instances of '=>', you need brackets around the anonymous function type:

```
null match { 
  case f: (() => Unit) => println("yep")
  case _ => println("nope")                      // prints nope


var i = 1

// input is a function with no args, returning Unit (not invoked)
{() => {i = i + 1; print("outer i=" + i + "  ")} } match { 
  case f : (() => Unit) => println("yep")       // prints yep
  case _ => print("nope")
}
```

Can also do this with a method:

```
// input is a function with no args, returning Unit (not invoked)
def myProc(a: () => Unit) = a match {
  case f: (() => Unit) => println("yep") 
  case _ => println("nope")
}

var i = 1
myProc({() => {i = i + 1; print("outer i=" + i + "  ")} })  // prints yep
```

The parameter a is a function.  The function result is not determined before the call - instead the expression which defines the function is evaluated before the call.  Then the function result is evaluated each time the parameter is evaluated (invoked) within the method (i.e. 0 times since it's only used in a pattern match, never invoked as `a()`)

```
// here, a is invoked 3 times
def myProc(a: () => Unit) = for (j <- 1 to 3) a()

var i = 1
myProc({() => {i = i + 1; print("outer i=" + i + "  ")} })  
// prints outer i=2  outer i=3  outer i=4
```

A similar (but not identical) thing can be done with non-function arguments (i.e. expressions/values).  Instead of declaring `a: SomeType` (a pass-by-value parameter, where the expression is evaluated before the call), can use `a: => SomeType` (a pass-by-name parameter, where the expression is not evaluated before the call, but is evaluated each time the argument is referenced within the method:

```
// input is a pass-by-name Unit expression
def myProc(a: => Unit) = a match {
  case f: Unit => println("yep") 
}

var i = 1
myProc({i = i + 1; print("outer i=" + i + "  ")})  // prints yep 

// input is a pass-by-name Unit expression
def myProc(a: => Unit) = {
  for (j <- 1 to 3) yield a
  a
}

var i = 1
myProc({i = i + 1; print("outer i=" + i + "  ")})  
// prints outer i=2  outer i=3  outer i=4  outer i=5
```